# vendor routes are not working after package install

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have installed [this package](https://github.com/stevemo/cpanel) in my *Laravel* application. The install appears to have gone smoothly and I ran the *artisan* commands as asked.

I also added the service providers and aliases as necessary. The issue I am having is that the routes that are specified by the vendor are not accessible. I see that the configs have published but when I try to use the `/admin` route it is not available.

also the service provider includes this:

```
    public function boot()
    {
            $this->package('stevemo/cpanel');
            include __DIR__ .'/routes.php';
    }
```

**is there anything else that needs to be done for the vendor routes to work?**

Comment: Do the routes appear when you run `php artisan routes`?

Comment: good question! turns out it was an issue with a filter in the package and my permissions in the sentry package. it was just redirecting me back to / which i don't have a route for.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out since I am using sentry with LDAP my sentry DB is a little different and it was a permissions issue on the route filter. routes are working fine now.